# How to test method from repository which marked as @Modifying?

Tags: java, junit, spring-data-jpa

For example I have

```
public interface CrudUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "UPDATE users SET active=?2 WHERE id=?1")
void setActive(long id, boolean active);
}
```

In my test I invoking this method and then find by id.

```
@Autowired
CrudUserRepository crudUser;
@Transactional
@Test
public void setActiveTest(){
    User user = getUser();
    crudUser.save(user);

    crudUser.setActive(user.getId(), true);
    Optional<User> optUser = crudUser.findById(user.getId());
    assert optUser.get().isActive(); //here my test falls
```

And when I perform `crudUser.findById(user.getId())` my optUser contains that user doesn't active but actually he's active (I've tested that by setting @Rollback(false) and manually check in db).

How I can test that case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `crudUser.save` will cache the entity. And when you call `crudUser.findById`, JPA just get the entity from the cache not from database. `crudUser.setActive` not update the `entity.active` in the cache. Change the code like bellow can fix it (clear the JPA cache) :

```
....
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
...
@Test
public void setActiveTest(){
  ...

  // clear the cache and force crudUser.findById from database
  entityManager.clear();

  Optional<User> optUser = crudUser.findById(user.getId());
  ...
}
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-modifying-annotation#clear 

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
```

is useful because it can force the repository to clear the context automatically after the Modifying operation is performed