# junit for native query

Tags: java, jpa, junit, nativequery

This is my repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface EntitlementRepository extends JpaRepository<Entitlement, Long> {

    Entitlement findByIdAndActiveTrue(Long entitlementId);

    List<Entitlement> findByIdInAndActiveTrue(Collection<Long> entitlementIds);

    List<Entitlement> findByIdIn(Collection<Long> entitlementIds);
    
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE ENTITLEMENT set RESTRICTION_LEVEL=:restrictionLevel where ID =:entitlementId", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateRestrictionLevel(@Param("restrictionLevel") String restrictionLevel, @Param("entitlementId") Long entitlementId);
}
```

This is my repository class junit:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class EntitlementRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private EntitlementRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() {
        Entitlement entitlementToAdd = anEntitlement("APPROVER1", "APPROVER2", "APPROVER3", null);
        Entitlement savedEnt = repository.save(entitlementToAdd); // create Entitlement with restriction null

        repository.updateRestrictionLevel("LEVEL11", savedEnt.getId()); // update restriction level 

        Entitlement updatedEnt = repository.findByIdAndActiveTrue(savedEnt.getId());
        assertThat(updatedEnt.getRestrictionLevel()).isEqualTo("LEVEL11");
    }
}
```

The restrictionLevel doesn't get updated. It stays null. Hence, assert statement fails.

Comment: Could your repository class methods be operating in the same transaction, so that the savedEnt==updatedEnt (ie are the same instance)?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [How to test method from repository which marked as @Modifying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857963/how-to-test-method-from-repository-which-marked-as-modifying)

Solved the problem by adding a entityManager.clear();

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class EntitlementRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private EntitlementRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testUpdate() {
        Entitlement entitlementToAdd = anEntitlement("APPROVER1", "APPROVER2", "APPROVER3", null);
        Entitlement savedEnt = repository.save(entitlementToAdd); // create Entitlement with restriction null

        repository.updateRestrictionLevel("LEVEL11", savedEnt.getId()); // update restriction level 
        entityManager.clear();
        Entitlement updatedEnt = repository.findByIdAndActiveTrue(savedEnt.getId());
        assertThat(updatedEnt.getRestrictionLevel()).isEqualTo("LEVEL11");
    }
}
```